# Genymotion virtual devices are not showing in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I am fairly new to mobile development. I am trying to get eclipse to run on genymotion given that it is much faster and efficient. I am nonetheless encountering a problem; eclipse doesnt really show a list of emulators that are running. I have installed the plugin for eclipse and configured the ADB to the android-sdk folder. I would really appreciate it if I could get some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you updated your android SDK to the last version?

Comment: no I haven't, I re-installed everything and I am currently using the command line interfase to create a cordova project instead of using the addon on eclipse. Also, re-installed the android SDK. Hopefully every works once I test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Android devices of same API which your SDK has, for EG: if you have Android SDK API 22, you need to clone the same or above version API(Google Nexus 5X -6.0.0 - API23) device in Genymotion.